# Display new page showing user input upon button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings, all. I'm working on a training project; I have a page for user input which I save to the database; now I need the submit button to bring up a static(?) form which only displays their input, with a link to go back and edit this input. I'm using C# and ASP.NET. Any ideas out there? The examples I found googling were semi-relevant, but I had a difficult time understanding, as I am ignorant to a near-criminal degree.

Comment: Just a note, I know how to use a redirect on the click event; where I get hung up is calling up the specific user's info.

Comment: Yes. You can call up the user's info from the session object. That's only after you set it on the prev page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to save the inputs into a session first. Not in db, because the user has not confirm on its value. Then Redirect to another page where you need to display the values from the session. Hope this helps.

Comment: A session object. *Googles inquisitively*

Comment: In page 1
Session["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;

In page 2
litFirstName.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString();

Comment: Where are my manners? Thank you, ysrb. I'd upvote you, but I'm only a level 8, which means no voting privileges.